# Как изменять базу данных postgres к которой подключен aiogram бот на удаленном сервере?

Tags: python, postgresql, aiogram

Ситуация следующая: есть бот, который работает на aiogram и long polling, на удаленном сервере и там же стоит бд, к которой подключен этот самый бот. У меня на локальном пк есть определенный скрипт, который создает какие то данные. Эти данные мне нужно закидывать в базу данных на удаленном сервере. Нашел 2 варианта: 1 - как то отправлять из скрипта запросы в телеграмм API, который в свою очередь будет отправлять запрос в моего бота, который создаст запись в бд (у меня в боте есть хендлеры, которые создают записи в бд). 2 - написать свое api на django и через эндпоинты как то пополнять бд. Какой вариант лучше? Или может кто то знает решение проще.

Comment: Почему бы ваш код не перенести на сервер? Пусть там себе крутится и сразу данные добавляет в бд.

Comment: Была такая идея, но для этого кода нужен совсем другой сервер с другими настройками)

Comment: Я бы выбрал второй вариант. Только апи защитить надо, что бы другие не смогли вам "лишнего" напихать